# NSMutableArray returns true for empty and nil both

Tags: ios, iphone

I have one NSMutableArray that returns nil and empty sometimes and I have if/else condition to check if array is empty or nil but it true for both.

Any good reason why?

```
    myArray = nil;
    if ([myArray count] == 0)
    {
       //do this
    }
    else if (myArray == nil)
    {
        // do that
    }
```

Comment: Can you show up some code ?...

Comment: @Thomasa added a code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working as expected. Your array is `nil`. When you call a method on a `nil` object, it will return `nil`, which is equal to `0` and `NO` (or `false` in Swift). Your code will always test true in the first `if` statement. If you want to check if the array is `nil`, put it before checking the count of the array.